# How much does Apple Pay really cost for person to person transactions?

Tags: apple-pay

In [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZRTlcB_vtA), Craig Federighi said that person-to-person transactions via Apple Pay cost no money if the user had a debit card.

It is hard to believe that for service and background processes they do not charge a penny. Is there any hidden cost?

Comment: Your personal data and spending habits are more valuable to them than a small fee

Comment: @DarrenH Not exactly. If you believe Apple then "Apple Pay doesn't collect any transaction information that can be tied back to you. Payment transactions are between you, the merchant (or developer for payments made within apps and on the web), and your bank" see support.apple.com/en-au/HT203027 Apple's main revenue does not come from selling targeted advertising based on large amounts of your personal data, unlike a number of other companies.

Comment: @DarrenH it’s not the personal data - it’s that you’ve bought an iPhone.

Comment: @DarrenH How can I advertise through Apple Ads? They must be very well targeted. Edit: Never mind - I've [found them](https://searchads.apple.com/). These seem to be deterministically based solely on the search query and the region and language settings, repeatable across many different devices...

Comment: @wizzwizz4 It is off the question topic, but since it was raised here, according to Apple the data used for search ads is aggregate data, i.e. it doesn't identify you, it is never sold to third parties, and you can opt out of contributing to aggregate data https://searchads.apple.com/privacy/

Answer (score 7):

It's the same as Venmo, zero for debit, 3% for credit.  Nothing hidden.

Comment: Same as Venmo *for now*. Once Apple has driven others out of the market, things may change.

Comment: Do you have a source for this, or did you just find out from your own experience?

Comment: @Thunderforge For personal experiences we will have to wait at least untii 11.1 is released.  Maybe for Halloween?